# How to define c# Version in ASP.Net markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, markup

I'm wondering if it is possible to use c# language features in ASP.Net Markup (*.aspx and *.ascx files) which were released after version 5.0. Is there a possibility to declare the markup language version in the header area of an aspx page?

I want to us the null propagation operator and getting following error:

```
Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 6 or greater.
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I hope that you just need to change your C# language version in your project settings:\

Comment: @vasily.sib That is not enough. See the duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks, you are right, solution in the mentioned topic works for me!